# Xserver broken and cannot restore

Tags: 14.04, xserver

I was installing ROS in Ubuntu 14.04.2 64bits while I installed these packages

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-dev-lts-utopic mesa-common-dev-lts-utopic libxatracker-dev-lts-utopic libopenvg1-mesa-dev-lts-utopic libgles2-mesa-dev-lts-utopic libgles1-mesa-dev-lts-utopic libgl1-mesa-dev-lts-utopic libgbm-dev-lts-utopic libegl1-mesa-dev-lts-utopic
```

Therefore my Xserver is broken. When I boot my PC it goes black screen before login and I cannot even go to the ttx terminals.

I have tried many things, and currently I have mounted the partitions as chroot in a livecd https://wiki.sabayon.org/index.php?title=HOWTO:_chroot_from_a_LiveCD and trying to do some commands I see in other websites:

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg
```

But the output is:

```
gnome-control-center Depends libcheese-gtk23 but is not going to be installed
                             libcheese7 but is not going to be installed
```

When I try to install those packages manually it says that they are already the newest version.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I removed the libcheese, then reinstalled it, and installed xserver-xorg-lts-quantal, and then reconfigured the xserver-xorg, then the normal desktop reappeared. I am not sure what solved the problem though.

Answer (score 2):

restart and boot to ubuntu recovery mode > in terminal

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libcheese-dev xserver-xorg
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
```

should work again from death